# Updating resource strings for ASP.Net MVC does not change the output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, resources, localizable.strings

I am trying to modify the string values for a resx file of an existing application. I have done nothing else apart from just changing the string value to replace a word (from "technician" to "agent"). File name and permissions are same, even the structure and naming convention is same.

Now, these changes do not reflect in IIS. I have restarted app pool, refreshed the application, double checked the permissions. Nothing seems wrong anywhere. I even tried the suggestions in older similar questions, but no luck.

I am not sure, if I need to recompile the whole solution, although, I believe that should not be the case. Do I need to do that? Also, will I have to republish the website from scratch, or can I just replace recompiled files in the IIS folder?

Or is there some other step I am missing?

Comment: I think you need to do a clean build and then just replace the main dll for your site in the bin folder.  What happens when you do that?

Comment: Let me check and get back to you in an hour or so.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. When I copied just the resx file, IIS removed the whole folder. Maybe it thought the folder was corrupt or something. Anyway, I moved the resources folder again, and the new dll, and changes show up fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a clean build and then just replace the main dll for your site in the bin folder. Sometimes Visual Studio doesn't see the change in resources and, in turn, it doesn't trigger a rebuild on your DLL.  Clean build ensures the changes are built.

Answer (score 0):

As per /u/Markus suggestion, I tried to build the code again. After changing the main dll file, and copying the resources folder again, it works.

Comment: I posted the answer. I've experienced this problem before, so I was 99% sure it would work.